# Extracting data from the ECB Data Warehouse

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, https, request

I would like to extract with Pandas a given value of the ECB Data Warehouse in [this page](https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/browse.do?node=bbn3215).

I have been going through the [ECB help page](https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/help/) but could not find the way to make it work.

I have tried the following code:

```
# Building blocks for the URL
entrypoint = 'https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/' # Using protocol 'https'
resource = 'data'           
flowRef ='BSI'              
key = 'M.AT.N.A.L20.A.1.U2'    

# Define the parameters
parameters = {
    'startPeriod': '2020-01-01',  # Start date of the time series
    'endPeriod': '2020-12-31'     # End of the time series
}  

request_url = entrypoint + resource + '/'+ flowRef + '/' + key
        
    # Make the HTTP request
    response = requests.get(request_url, params=parameters)
    
    # Check if the response returns succesfully with response code 200
    print(response)
    
    # Print the full URL
    print(response.url)
```

I keep getting the error code:

```
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool - OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))
```

I would be extremely thankful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the HTTPS_PROXY to get out of your network :)